# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object with get_term_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting a notice "Trying to get property of non-object" in a WordPress theme

The line 5, notice is showing the following code but everything seems to be ok:

```
$age = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'age',true);
```

Output:

```
if( ! empty($age)) {
echo '<p>'.__('Age','framework').': <span>'.$age.'</span></p>';
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here? How can I remove this notice?
Thanks.

Comment: `$term->term_id` is the problem. Odds are `$term` is `null`.

Comment: Check the content of ```$term``` . May be there is no ```term_id``` exist inside ```$term``` object.

Comment: its `$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this line is throwing the notice:

```
$age = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'age',true);
```

You need to check first if $term->term_id is set:

```
if( isset($term->term_id) ){
    $age = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'age',true);
}
```

Also have in mind that this notices may not be displaying in the prod server.

Comment: thanks Agustin but the problem was another thing.The variables are in a sidebar which is visible also in a page template and I just got the variables in `if ( is_tax('my_tax') ) {` and everything works fine, thanks for your answer I changed also ! empty with isset as you suggested and its better now.